# Using dnsmasq with wildcard on Mac

Tags: macos, dns, homestead, dnsmasq

I'd like to point all *.test domains to my Laravel Homestead machine on 192.168.10.10. I used to have it working with *.dev domains, but after new *.dev policy implemented by Chrome 63, I prefer to change it to *.test.

I fail to understand how local DNS works, as it seems to use trillion different configs and caches. What I did is:

1. Making sure 192.168.10.10 with HTTP Host set to `me.test` works. It works.
2. In `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, I do have an entry `address=/.test/192.168.10.10` (I also tried with 127.0.0.1)
3. In `/etc/resolver/test` file, I put `nameserver 127.0.0.1` - it used to work this way with `/etc/resolver/dev`. I still don't understand why it's `127.0.0.1` and not `192.168.10.10`. I tried both anyway.
4. Clearing DNS cache with `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper; sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`
5. Restarting dnsmasq with `sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq; sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq`.
6. Trying to visit `http://me.test/`.

It doesn't work. The domain will take forever to be loaded and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

My OS is High Sierra, dnsmasq installed via homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use dnsmasq, but I believe you want to edit `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and have `listen-address=127.0.0.1` set so dnsmasq is listening on that IP, but have `address=/.test/192.168.10.10` so that `.test` is routed to `192.168.10.10`.

Then make sure System Preferences -> Advanced you have 127.0.0.1 as the first DNS server entry for your connection.

Make sure you're restarting dnsmasq every time you edit the configuration file.

Comment: I did that and it works :) But I'm still curious - why did it work before, without `127.0.0.1` on my DNS in OS settings list. Also, it still works without `listen-address` in `dnsmasq.conf`. There are so many things I don't get there it's driving me annoyed.

Comment: So if dnsmasq points to an IP, why is a resolver still needed?